# d3.js - determining nested depth (or children of children)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, nested, depth

I have a data visualization which currently gives objects a class based on whether or not they have children, like this:

```
d3.json("skills.json", function(error, root) {
  var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
```

what I want to do is give them a different class based on their depth, or at the very least, based on whether they have children of children, essentially like this (though I'm not sure of the syntax):

```
.attr("class", function(d) { return d.children.children ? "node" ? d.children ? "branch" : "leaf node"; });
```

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if any of the current node’s children have children.

```
node.attr("class", function(d) {
  return d.children ? (d.children.some(function(c) { return c.children; })
      ? "grandparent" 
      : "parent")
      : "child";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The D3.js API contains an undocumented method `d.depth` that tracks the depth of the nodes from the root.